# Bringing Python layout algorithm to Cytoscape

Tags: python, java, networking, cytoscape

We would like to bring one of our layout algorithms, which is implemented in Python, to Cytoscape. As Cytoscape apps are written in Java, I was wondering whether some of you has an idea on how to easily bring it to Cytoscape without rewriting the Algorithm in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Dexter already reached out to you, but the easiest path would be to use a REST service of some sort, either a local one or one on a remote server.